# Is it possible to loop through variables, with numbers appended to the variables name, in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm attempting to write a bash script that collects information via SNMPv3 and generates a configuration template for a given device.

My goal is to generate a template based on the variables *mibnumberX* and *interfaceX* with X being a number determined by user input (eg. how many interfaces would you like to add? what are the names of the interfaces?)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ambiguously defined variables for the sake of demonstration:

authpriv="authPriv"
devicetype="ASA"
snmpuser="username"
authhash="SHA"
authstring="authpassword"
privhash="AES"
privstring="privpassword"
ipaddress="1.1.1.1"
interface1="Inside"
interface2="Outside"
numberofifs="2"
defaultasa="yes"


# Determine how many interfaces are to be added and what their friendly names are

if [[ $defaultasa = "yes" ]];
  then
    read -p "How many interfaces would you like to add to monitoring for this device? " numberofifs
    for ((i = 1; i <= numberofifs; i++))
    do
      read -p "Please enter the name of interface number ${i} and press [ENTER]: " interface${i}
    done
fi


# Walk the ifDescr MIBs, grep with the friendly name of the interface(s) and store the last number of IF-MIB::ifDescr.16 in *mibnumberX*.

if [[ $authpriv = "authPriv" ]] && [[ $devicetype = "ASA" ]];
  then
  for ((i = 1; i <= numberofifs; i++))
  do
    eval "ifnumber=\$interface$i"
    eval "mibnumber$i=$(snmpwalk -v3 -u $snmpuser -l AuthPriv -a $authhash -A $authstring -x $privhash -X $privstring $ipaddress ifD | grep -i $ifnumber | awk -F"[<.=>]" '{print $2}')"
  done
fi


# Display interface names and MIBs

printf "Name: $interface1\n MIB number: $mibnumber1\nName: $interface2\n MIB Number: $mibnumber2\n"
```

Script results:

```
$ ./test.sh
Name: Inside
 MIB number: 15
Name: Outside
 MIB Number: 16
```

The intention is to cycle through the *mibnumberX* and *interfaceX* variables and print out the following template with them sprinkled in whether there are two interfaces being added or two hundred.

```
if [[ $authpriv = "authPriv" ]];
  then
        for ((i = 1; i <= numberofifs; i++))
    do
        printf "\ndefine service{
         service_description     Interface $interface$i
         check_command           check_snmp_V3-2!$snmpuser!$authstring!$privhash!$privstring!$authpriv!$authhash!.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.$mibnumber${i}!-r 1 -m RFC1213-MIB!-l Interface \n} \n\n"
    done
fi
```

However, the output of this section is providing no such luck:

```
    $ ./test.sh
Name: Inside
 MIB number: 15
Name: Outside
 MIB Number: 16

define service{
             service_description     Interface 1
             check_command           check_snmp_V3-2!username!authpassword!AES!privpassword!authPriv!SHA!.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.1!-r 1 -m RFC1213-MIB!-l Interface
}

define service{
         service_description     Interface 2
         check_command           check_snmp_V3-2!username!authpassword!AES!privpassword!authPriv!SHA!.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.2!-r 1 -m RFC1213-MIB!-l Interface
}
```

I'm a novice experimenting with bash and am open to any suggestions.

Comment: I haven't parsed your entire code, but why couldn't you use arrays?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. The more research I do on this problem, the more I'm led to using  arrays. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to incorporate an array as a solution successfully due to my lack of understanding in regards to arrays in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an unlimited number of possible entries, you should use [Bash's arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) as data structures, rather than introducing a new variable for each entry.

All you need to do is replace the line where you ask for the name with this (text shortened for readability):

```
read -p "Please enter the name … press [ENTER]: " interface[$i]
```

Now, `$interface` will be an array, containing the names of the interfaces. You can iterate over the entries by using a typical `for` loop, where `${interface[@]}` expands to all the entries:

```
for name in "${interface[@]}"; do echo "$name"; done
```

You can also easily use this within your `for ((…))` loops to access the array element at index `$i` with `$interface[$i]`, like we did when assigning the name.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. I tested `read`ing the input into the `$interface` array and it worked great. I had to use `${interface[$i]}` in the `for ((...))` loop and it's now working brilliantly. However, I'm unclear how I can iterate through the `$interface` array in the `for ((...))` loop `do eval`, and feed the results of the `eval` into an array. I was trying to iterate with a number appended to the variable with no luck. `eval "mibnumber$i=$(snmpwalk ... | grep -i $interface[$i] | awk -F"[<.=>]" '{print $2}')"`

Comment: @one.time The *only* syntax which works for subscripting a bash array is `${array[index]}`. `$array[index]` does not work (unless you wanted what it produces, which is the same as `${array[0]}[index]`. In other words, unlike non-array variables, the braces `{}` are *not optional*.

Comment: @one.time It should simply be `mibnumber[$i]=$(…)`, just like in the assignment to `interface` we used in the original loop.